# Question about a unary operation on digraphs.

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

Let $D=(V_{D}, A_{D})$ be a *digraph*. We're going to define an operation $\partial(D)$, where $$V_{\partial(D)} = A_{D},$$ $$A_{\partial(D)} = \{((w,v),(v,u))|(w,v) \in A_{D} \land (v,u) \in A_{D} \}.$$

Here's an example of this operation:

[image]
[image]
[image].

So I'm wondering if this operation has been studied and written about. Does it have a name, are there any papers I could look at? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the "directed line graph" or "[line digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph#Line_digraphs)" or sometimes "arc digraph". It's a generalization of the line graph (which is just the undirected version of your operation). They were first introduced in a [1960 paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02854581) by Harary and Norman, which unfortunately I haven't been able to find anywhere that isn't asking for USD 39.95 to access the article. But you could start looking from the list of [citations of this paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=16712003441351195931) if you wanted to see what's been done with line digraphs since then.

(Admittedly, that list will give you just about everything even tangentially related to line digraphs, including results about something else that used a lemma about them somewhere. Perhaps we'd better narrow it down; [97 of them](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=digraph&cites=16712003441351195931&scipsc=1) actually have the word "digraph" somewhere searchable.)